# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: linq

I am working on these lists to get an item that matches the selected item from the combobox.

```
private void InitializaMessageElement()
{
    if (_selectedTransactionWsName != null)
    {
```

1. get a transaction webservice name matching the selected item from the drop down here the output=TestWS  which is correct

   ```
   var getTranTypeWsName = TransactionTypeVModel
        .GetAllTransactionTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(transTypes => 
                transTypes.WsMethodName == _selectedTransactionWsName);
   ```
2. Loop the list of wsnames from the treenode list. Here it gives me all the node I have which is correct.

   ```
   var wsNameList = MessageElementVModel
        .GetAllTreeNodes().Select(ame => 
                ame.Children).ToList();//. == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName);
   ```
3. find the getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName in the  wsNameList. Here is where I have the problem:

   ```
         var msgElementList = wsNameList.Select(x => x.Where(ame => getTranTypeWsName != null && ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName)).ToList();
   ```

my MsgElement list:

```
   _msgElementObsList = new ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel>(msgElementList);
    this.messageElements = _msgElementList;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageElements");
}
```

Here it is throwing exception `Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to System.Collections.Generic.List).`

Comment: Which line exactly does the compiler throw the exception for?

Comment: MsgElementObsList = new ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel>(msgElementList);   ... msgElementList is the one with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a List of IEnumerable not a List of MessageElementViewModel. That is why you are throwing an error.

Not sure which one you need but you could fix your Select function like this.

```
var msgElementList = wsNameList.Select(x => x.Where(ame => getTranTypeWsName != null && ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName).First()).ToList();
```

or

```
var msgElementList = wsNameList.SelectMany(x => x.Where(ame => getTranTypeWsName != null && ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you rework your `msgElementList` to

```
var msgElementList = wsNameList.Where(x => x.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName).ToList();?
```

The `getTranTypeWsName != null` doesn't belong in there I don't think because it doesn't compare with any of the lambda's members.

Comment: Thank you. Got answer from @Ceres